# NSMutableArray crashes app when adding objects

Tags: animation, crash, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Xcode 4 with Cocos2D on Mac OS X 10.6.8. I am trying to use a sprite sheet for an animation. This is the code I have:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"scrollAnimation.plist"];
CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"scrollAnimation.png"];
[self addChild:spriteSheet];

NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    [animFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"scroll%d.png", i]]];
}

self.scrollAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames delay:0.05f];

self.scroll = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"scroll0.png"];
_scroll.position = ccp(_winSize.width*1.5, _winSize.height*1.5);
[spriteSheet addChild:_scroll];
```

This works alright in the simulator, but when I get a device build, it crashes. I have narrowed it down to adding the objects to the array. If I comment everything out from before the for loop, then just add the spriteFrameByName part, it works. But when I try and put that into a array, the app crashes on a device.

Any help?

Comment: don't you have any error message with the crash? what does the stack trace look like at that moment?

Comment: For some reason, I can't get any error message when testing on my device. It works perfectly on the simulator though, so I don't get any errors there.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for this kind of behavior is that your app occupies all the memory it has and the OS kills it. I am saying this because it is very typical that in such cases you don't get any hints from the crash log, and is also typical when your app works in the simulator but not in the device.

So, to investigate the issue I would first check if there are memory warning traces (if covos2d has tracing enabled) before the crash. That would be a clear sign.

Actually, there is a second possible outcome when you get a memory warning that also leads to a crash.  Your app receives a memory warning (look at cocos2d traces); your texture cache gets emptied, so when you try and use a texture you thought you pre cached, the app crashes. But in this case the error would be more verbose. If you think the problem is related to this, have a look at this post: http://labs.freescapes.org/blog/2011/07/cocos2d-and-memory-warnings/

Answer (score 0):

One reason I've found for things working in the simulator but not working on the device is because the name of the file is typed wrong.  I'd check to make sure the name of scrollAnimation.plist isn't really ScrollAnimation.plist or scrollanimation.plist and same thing with scroll0.png that it's not really named Scroll0.png